# Redirect page based on lack of a URL parameter or if parameter is null- PHP

Tags: php, url, redirect, if-statement, url-parameters

I have a URL e.g. http://foo.com?stone=yes

The page pointing to that URL is coded in PHP.

I can use the following to read stone.

I want to be able to redirect the page if:

1. stone's value is null
2. stone isn't present in the URL.

I've tried the following but it's not working.

```
 $stonevar = $_GET['stone'];

 if ($stonevar = "") {
    header("Location: http://google.com");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some erros in your code.

1- If you don't check if the $_GET['stone'] exist you will get a warning like: *Undefine variable...*

2- In your `if` stament you're assigning a value, to compare values use `==` or `===` instead.

Change your code to:

```
$stonevar = isset($_GET['stone']) ? $_GET['stone'] : NULL;

if (empty($stonevar)) {
  header("Location: http://google.com");
  exit();
}
```

Useful links:

[isset](https://www.php.net/isset)

[empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

[Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

[Ternary Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with [empty()](https://www.php.net/empty)

```
<?php

if(empty($_GET['stone'])) {
    header("Location: http://google.com");
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I deleted my comment as soon as I noticed that you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The code `$stonevar = ""` in your if condition is assigning the value "" to the variable `$stonevar`.

For comparison, you will want to use the equality operator `==`, e.g.:

```
 if ($stonevar == "") {
 header("Location: http://google.com");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(empty($_GET['stone'])) {
header("Location: http://google.com");
}
?>
```

Comment: Please improve the quality of this answer by adding more than just a code snippet.